# shadowbox horizontal scrollbar not showing in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shadowbox

I am using [shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) to open different links on a website. For some reason, Firefox does not show the horizontal scrollbar. It works fine in all other browsers.

I have tried this with no luck :(

```
<a href="http://exmaple.com" rel="shadowbox;width=200;height=200;scrolling=yes">link</a>
```

I have also tried the following on the iframe page:

```
html {
     overflow: -moz-scrollbars-horizontal;
     overflow: scroll;
}
```

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shadowbox.css line 9 contains:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Which hides the horizontal scrollbar.

You could overrule this by adding `!important`:

```
body {
    overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `default.css` file and try:

```
html, body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```